# while-loop finishes a loop but takes a long time to begin the next loop

Tags: c++, performance, loops, time, while-loop

I am programming in C++ and implementing a large scale algorithm in optimization area. I have a huge while loop with many stuff inside it. The condition of the loop is just a comparison of two integer numbers `a` and `b`. I report the time in two points:

1- when the program reaches the end of the while loop.

2- when the program is at the beginning of the while loop.

The code is like the following

```
        while (a<b){
            //Report time at the beginning of the loop
            time_t beginT = time(0);
            char* dtBegin = ctime (&beginT);
            cout << "Time at the beginning of the loop: " << dtBegin << endl;
            .
            .
            . //all of the other functions inside the loop
            //Report time at the end of the loop
            time_t endT = time(0);
            char* dtEnd = ctime (&endT);
            cout << "Time at the end of the loop: " << dtEnd << endl;
        }
```

when the program reaches the end of the loop, it takes a long time to go back to the beginning of the loop i.e., it can take around 20 minutes for large input instances. I should emphasize that all of the operations inside the loop are executed and time is reported, and this 20 minutes is just for the program to return to the beginning of the loop.

I wonder what is this time spent on and how can I reduce it?

Any help is appreciated.

P.S. The dots in the loop indicate the confidential part of the code which cannot be shared.

Comment: What platform are you running this on, and what is the load on that system?

Comment: A few things.  Are you sure that your messages get flushed immediately (e.g. on terminal, line buffering in effect, but output to log needs explicit flush)?  If you've got _big_ data, are you paging/swapping (e.g. 10GB RAM but using 50GB swap)?  It _can_ take 20 minutes to page out/page in.  While you can't post proprietary code, how about the time messages for a few rounds?  This shows time _within_ the "loop" and start/stop times.

Comment: That kind of behavior is usually caused by RAM management... but 20 minutes ? That can only be a SWAP. RAM defrag does not take 20 minutes...

Comment: Any objects created in the scope of your loop will be destroyed at the closing brace.   If these are large and complex, this may take a while.

Comment: what if you replace `std::cout` with `std::cerr`?

Answer (score 3):

Your instrumentation is broken, counting destructors for objects at loop scope as outside the end of the loop. The fix is this simple:

```
    while (a<b){
        //Report time at the beginning of the loop
        time_t beginT = time(0);
        char* dtBegin = ctime (&beginT);
        cout << "Time at the beginning of the loop: " << dtBegin << endl;
        {
            .
            .
            . //all of the other functions inside the loop
        }
        //Report time at the end of the loop
        time_t endT = time(0);
        char* dtEnd = ctime (&endT);
        cout << "Time at the end of the loop: " << dtEnd << endl;
    }
```

Now, the loop internals have their own scope, the destructors run when that scope is exited, and they're properly accounted for as time spent in that iteration of the loop.

Comment: Or add more instrumentation - time the internals as well as the destructors.

Comment: Your solution just changes the place where the delay occurs. Instead of happening after printing the time, it lingers before it.

Comment: @hmd.pouya Right. The issue was that the delay occurred in the wrong place, causing you to be unable to know where the time was being spent or how to reduce it. Now it occurs in the right place and you know what it is (destructors at loop scope).

Comment: @David, You are right. And now, what is your suggestion to make the destruction process faster?

Comment: I can't tell you how to optimize code without seeing the code. Maybe you can re-use the structures rather than destroying them. Maybe the destructor destroys things in a maximally inefficient order. Maybe it acquires fine-grained locks unnecessarily. Maybe you can get huge benefits from using a custom allocator. I don't know.